# How to make Geo::Coder::Google run even if input location doesn't exist

Tags: perl, geolocation

I'm trying to use `Geo::Coder::Google` to get a list of coordinates from an array of locations. My problem is that the array of locations is generated by an another script which sometimes puts in it some strange locations which can not be found in google maps, i.e. *CorseMétéo*.

This generates the following error message :

```
"Google Maps API returned error: 500 Can't connect to maps.google.com:80 (Bad hostname) at geoTest.pl line 24.".
```

My code looks like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use locale;
use warnings;
#use diagnostics;
use utf8;

binmode(STDIN, "encoding(utf8)");
binmode(STDOUT, "encoding(utf8)");
binmode(STDERR, "encoding(utf8)");

use Geo::Coder::Google;

my @place = ('Daluis', 'Corse', 'CorseMétéo');
my ($long, $lat);

foreach my $place(@place){
     my $geocoder = Geo::Coder::Google->new(apikey => '{MyAPIkey}');

     my $response;
     until (defined $response){
         $response = $geocoder->geocode(location => $place);
         }
     ($long, $lat) = @{ $response->{Point}{coordinates} };
     print "$long\n";
     print "$lat\n";
 }
```

Usually this perl module is used to geolocate street address, however it seems to run pretty good on bigger geographic locations.

Anybody had a similar problem ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to keep going even if there is an error, use an [`eval` block](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html):

```
 until (defined $@ or defined $response){
     eval {
          $response = $geocoder->geocode(location => $place);
     }
 }

 if ($@)
 {
     #some error handling.
 }
```

Note that `eval { BLOCK }` is not the same as `eval "string of code"`.  It doesn't compile the code at run-time, and it isn't a security problem.  It is just a simple way of exception handling.

Comment: @Krishna, see the documentation for eval http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html

Comment: It still gives me an error, and it doesn't work at all. I get : Useless use of a constant (#some error handling) in void context at geoTest.pl line 29.
Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at geoTest.pl line 31. It seems that $@ is conflict whit the ($long, $lat) = @{ $response->{Point}{coordinates} }.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a way to keep it working, it looks like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use locale;
use warnings;
#use diagnostics;
use utf8;

binmode(STDIN, "encoding(utf8)");
binmode(STDOUT, "encoding(utf8)");
binmode(STDERR, "encoding(utf8)");

use Geo::Coder::Google;


my @place = ('Daluis', 'Corse', 'CorseMétéo', 'New Delhi');
my ($long, $lat);

foreach my $place(@place){
    my $geocoder = Geo::Coder::Google->new(apikey => '{MyAPIkeyHere}');

    my $response;
    until (defined $response){
        eval{
            $response = $geocoder->geocode(location => $place);
            if ($@){
                "Couldn't get location : $place\n";
            }else{
                ($long, $lat) = @{ $response->{Point}{coordinates} };
            }
        }

    }
    print "$place\n";
    print "$long\n";
    print "$lat\n";     
}
```

The thing is now, each time a location isn't found, the coordinates from the previous location are pushed in it. So afterwards it's just a matter of getting rid of the duplicates. I use the coordinates to fill a JavaScript in order to generate a location map with google maps API.
However, the code will still generate an error output :

```
Useless use of a constant (Couldn't get location) in void context at get_LatLng.pl line 48.
```

But the code works for now. If anybody has any idea how to manage this error it would be nice.

Thank you anyway !!!